# Django NoReverseMatch for a Particular User

Tags: python, django

This is quite surprising and I can't seem to get my way around it.

The code below works for most users but it breaks when I try to render a link for user **SSenior** generating the error below:

**NoReverseMatch at /tofollow/
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(u'SSenior ',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P\w+)/$']**

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tofollow/$', views.tofollow, name='tofollow'),
url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'mysite:profile' users.username %}">@{{user.username}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username has a space in the end of it.

```
u'SSenior '
```

The regex `\w+` does not match spaces, therefore you get the `NoReverseMatch` error.

Remove the space (you could use the Django admin to do this) and it will work.

Comment: Django admin? How do I use it?

Comment: If you have the Django admin enabled, you should be able to edit the user if you go to `example.com/admin/auth/user`, and log in as a superuser.